# Karma-Jasmine setup for Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, jasmine2.0

I have an angular(currently @4.0.0) project for which I want to introduce Unit Testing using Karma and Jasmine.

I have set up the appropriate `karma.conf.js`, `spec-bundle.js` and `package.json`. But when I run `npm test`, this is what is on the console. The test scripts dont seem to be recognized and run.

[image]

And these are the warnings on the  console,
[image]

I have a `spec` file with simple test for `app.ts`.

```
import { async, TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { App } from './app';
import { AuthorizationService } from '../service/security/authorizationService';


describe('App (templateUrl)', () => {
   let comp: App;
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<App>;
   let de: DebugElement;
   let el: HTMLElement;

   beforeEach(async(() => {
     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       declarations: [App]
     })
       .compileComponents();
   }));

   beforeEach(() => {
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(App);
     comp = fixture.componentInstance;
   });

   it('should display app title', () => {
     fixture.detectChanges();
     expect(comp.appTitle).toContain('Angular');
   });
});
```

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
"rimraf": "rimraf",
"tslint": "tslint",
"typedoc": "typedoc",
"typings": "typings",
"webpack": "webpack",
"webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
"webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
"protractor": "protractor",
"clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc typings coverage dist",
"clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
"preclean:install": "npm run clean",
"clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
"preclean:start": "npm run clean",
"clean:start": "npm start",
"watch": "npm run watch:local",
"watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
"watch:local": "npm run build:local -- --watch",
"watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
"watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
"watch:uat": "npm run uat -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
"watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
"build": "npm run build:local",
"prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
"build:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
"build:local": "webpack --config config/webpack.local.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
"build:devplus": "webpack --config config/webpack.devplus.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
"build:test": "webpack --config config/webpack.test.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached --bail",
"build:uat": "webpack --config config/webpack.uat.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached --bail",
"prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
"build:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached --bail",
"server": "npm run server:dev",
"server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --inline --progress --profile --colors --watch --display-error-details --display-cached --content-base src/",
"server:local": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.local.js --inline --progress --profile --colors --watch --display-error-details --display-cached --content-base src/",
"server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --hot",
"server:prod": "http-server dist --cors",
"webdriver:update": "npm run webdriver-manager update",
"webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
"lint": "npm run tslint 'src/**/*.ts'",
"pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
"e2e": "npm run protractor",
"e2e:live": "npm run e2e -- --elementExplorer",
"pretest": "npm run lint",
"test": "karma start config/karma.conf.js",
"ci": "npm run e2e && npm run test",
"docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
"start": "npm run server:local",
"start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
"postinstall": "npm run typings -- install",
"preversion": "npm test",
"version": "npm run build",
"postversion": "git push && git push --tags"
},

"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "4.0.0",
"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/upgrade": "4.0.0",
"angular2-toaster": "1.0.1",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"css-loader": "0.23.1",
"fullcalendar": "^2.7.1",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"intl": "1.2.4",
"jquery": "2.2.2",
"jquery-ui": "1.10.5",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"ng2-auto-complete": "^0.7.0",
"ng2-cookies": "^0.1.5",
"ng2-file-upload": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
"node-sass": "^3.8.0",
"normalize.css": "^4.1.1",
"path-to-regexp": "^1.5.3",
"postcss": "^5.0.19",
"postcss-loader": "^0.8.2",
"primeng": "1.0.0-beta.15",
"primeui": "4.1.10",
"resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.0",
"rxjs": "^5.0.1",
"sass-loader": "^3.2.3",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"tether": "^1.2.0",
"url-loader": "^0.5.7",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2-hmr": "~0.5.5",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "~0.17.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple": "^6.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-es2015-webpack": "^6.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "bootstrap-loader": "1.0.10",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.15",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
    "es6-promise-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.6.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.6.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.7.0",
    "lodash": "^4.6.1",
    "moment": "^2.11.2",
    "node-sass": "3.7.0",
    "npmconf": "2.1.2",
    "parse5": "^2.1.5",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "^3.2.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.6.3",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.4.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^0.7.1",
    "tslint": "^3.7.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.3",
    "typedoc": "^0.3.12",
    "typescript": "2.0.3",
    "typings": "^1.5.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-load-plugins": "^0.1.2",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.12.0",
    "webpack-validator": "^1.0.0-beta.4"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function(config) {

var testWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.test.js');

  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    exclude: [ ],

files: [ { pattern: 'spec-bundle.js', watched: false } ],

preprocessors: { 'spec-bundle.js': ['coverage', 'webpack', 'sourcemap'] },

webpack: testWebpackConfig,

coverageReporter: {
  dir : 'coverage/',
  reporters: [
    { type: 'text-summary' },
    { type: 'json' },
    { type: 'html' }
  ]
},
webpackServer: { noInfo: true },

reporters: [ 'mocha', 'coverage' ],
port: 9876,

colors: true,
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

autoWatch: true,

browsers: [
  'Chrome'
],
singleRun: true

 });

};
```

spec-bundle.js:

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

require('core-js/es6');
require('core-js/es7/reflect');

require('zone.js/dist/zone');
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
require('zone.js/dist/proxy'); // since zone.js 0.6.15
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');
require('zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch'); // put here since zone.js 0.6.14
require('zone.js/dist/async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');
require('rxjs/Rx');

var testing = require('@angular/core/testing');
var browser = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');

testing.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
  browser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  browser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

var testContext = require.context('../src', true, /\.spec\.ts/);

function requireAll(requireContext) {
  return requireContext.keys().map(requireContext);
}

var modules = requireAll(testContext);
```

Comment: can you try to rename the file to `karma.config.js` please? And/or show the package.json and the karma config file you have?

Comment: @quirimmo Changed the file to `karma.config.js` and continued to get the same issues along with errors in the application files. Edited the question with `package.json` and 'karma.conf.js`

Comment: can you add this to your package.json please?
"scripts": {
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js"
}

Comment: Yes, i already have `"test" : "karma start config/karma.conf.js"` in `package.json, scripts`

Comment: I can't see it in the package.json you pasted

Comment: can you try to change your test command to the following please?
`concurrently \"npm run tsc -p *" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"`

Comment: I changed the test script to `concurrently \"npm run tsc -p *" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"` , but ended up with the same issue as mentioned in the question. I tested with test script `describe('1st tests', () => {
  it('true is true', () => expect(true).toBe(true));
});`
and it works (I see the test result in the console)

I'm thinking there is some problem with my code in `app.spec.ts`

Comment: this error mostly occurs, if something is wrong withing your spec-bundle.ts. could you post this file here?

Comment: one other thing, have you tried to move the "fixture.detectChanges();" command inside the BeforeEach() function?

Comment: @AnkeKnicker I added the `spec-bundle.js` for your reference. Also moving  `fixture.detectChanges()` into `beforeEach()` did not help. The first warning points to the import statement of the component I'm trying to test. Does it have anything to do with `babel`? These are the packages I have related to babel

`  
    `   "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
        "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
        "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple": "^6.7.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
        "babel-preset-es2015-webpack": "^6.4.0", `

Comment: @user3344978 Just as a sanity check, can you change this not to test angular? Just write a dummy test that 1==1 so we know whether is a karma config problem or an Angular config problem. Also,  why are you using babel? Isn't this TypeScript?

Comment: @JuanMendes I tried to use this simple test to test karma config and it works

 `describe('1st tests', () => {
//   it('true is true', () => expect(true).toBe(true));
// });`

Comment: We haven't used `async()` in any of my tests and we call it from `beforeEach()` Maybe remove that?

Comment: @JuanMendes Since this is my first time, I was following the Angular testing instructions, where `async()` is used when there are external `html` templates. Can I reference `templateUrls` through ` .compileComponents();` without using `async()` ?

Comment: @user3344978 My example uses it, but even for asynchronous stuff, I never use async, I always use the `done` callback instead of the `async` function, I thought it was deprecate, but don't quote me on it.

Comment: @JuanMendes I am thinking `async() ` is not deprecated because as per [this page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#atu-apis), it seems to be valid. 
Moreover, I tried testing without the `async()` but still doesnt work. I'm not sure why `import` statements are giving me this issue